# What verification would I need to present for picking up a ticket at the airport?

Tags: air-travel, paperwork

I'm going to be flying from Harrisburg, Pennsylvania to Dallas, Texas... I don't have current identification for Pennsylvania but I have an expired identification card to prove who I am. Will that work or should the person purchasing the ticket just print the boarding pass and mail it to me?

Comment: Note that some airlines have specific policies for tickets for one person paid by another, and may ask to see the credit card used to pay for the ticket at some point. Double check your airline's policies on this subject in advance to avoid any surprises. They usually make it quite clear during the booking process and in confirmation e-mails, though.

Comment: You’ll need current id to fly on the flight anyway. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

You will not collect a physical ticket from a ticket desk; air tickets are now electronic. You can print a boarding pass using any valid identification at the airport, or you can log on to your airline's website with your five/six digit reference and your surname and print your boarding pass at home. You will need valid identification to take your domestic flight, please see https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification